# How can I combine two existing Windows installations on different partitions, one disk to make a dual boot system?

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, ssd

I want to create a dual-booted system, combining one existing Win10 and one existing Win7 installation. So far, I managed  to
copy them both to one SSD (GPT) with partition software, the Win10 installation first, and with a BCD-editor I even made a start-up menu.
But when I try to boot into the  Win7 installation it gives a 0xc000428 error.
How do I solve this?

EDIT: The Win10 installation is now booting up fine, and even the Win7 installation worked, until I tried to make them swap places. Originally, the Win7 sat on the SSD in first place, and the Win10 came after. I then copied the partitions to another disk, so that now the Win10 came first, and the Win7 came second. The Win7 partition is still accessible, it just doesn't boot no more. There's a small EFI partition of 260 MB, completely in front of the SSD.

Therefor, what I nééd is a way to restore the boot capability of the Win7 installation .... if this is impossible .... i suppose i might be helped with hints on how to make a VM or VHD of the Win7 installation. Seems a scary, daunting thing. Big CPU print.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Please see the edit above. On what else would you like info?

Comment: So both installations are on the same PC?

Comment: Yes, they are even on the same physical drive, an SSD, right now.....